# how to get a non repeated element in scala val ele = List (1,2,3,4,2,3,5,6) output(1,4,5,6) only non repeated elements

Tags: scala

Given

```
val ele = List (1,2,3,4,2,3,5,6)
```

I want output like this

```
val ele1 = List(1,4,5,6)
```

Only the non-repeated elements.

Answer (score 2):

Explained differently, you want to **filter** elements for which the **count** of their occurences is only one.

Luckily, scala provides function for both those keywords !

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6)
val result = list.filter(element => list.count(_ == element) == 1)
```

Note that this function is not computationally optimal, but it's easy to read and to relate to the english formulation :-)

Comment: What a nice answer! ;)

Comment: Well, it's pretty basic, but thank you :-)

Comment: Yeap, I especially like how you derive the solution from the properly stated requirements. But for sure the algorithmic complexity could be explained better. :D

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution that's not terribly performant but it's pretty easy to understand.

```
val ele     = List (1,2,3,4,2,3,5,6,2)
val distEle = ele.distinct                     //List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
val rslt    = distEle diff (ele diff distEle)  //List(1, 4, 5, 6)
```

1. Get a `List` of all the distinct elements.
2. Remove those from the original `List` of all elements. This creates a `List` of the repeated elements.
3. Remove the repeated elements from the distinct elements.

The result preserves the order of unique elements as they appeared in the original list.

Comment: BEWARE: Both `diff` and `distinct` use  Scala's `HashMap` and `HashSet` accordingly underhood. So, both are vulnerable under attacks which exploit hash code collisions: github.com/scala/bug/issues/11203

Comment: Good point. @SahithyaKari, be aware that, when doing your CS assignments, you could be exposing yourself to possible cyber attacks, mad cow disease, and really bad haircuts. My advice: go into politics, where your mistakes are someone else's problems.

Comment: Sahithya, thinking about algorithmic complexity for worst cases at the CS homework will save your business in the future. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190723234535/https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2019/07/23/efficiently-generating-python-hash-collisions/) is a nice article about that.

Comment: Well played. [Back at ya](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/).